# Rails extremely slow

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, performance, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Sorry I know this is a generic question, I'll try to provide as much detail as possible

I am running Bitnami Rubystack (3.2.7) on Amazon EC2 Medium instance. and some aspects of Rails are extremely slow, here are some of them:

- when logging in (I am using devise gem), if you provide an invalid password, it would take a long time to tell you that the password is invalid.
- Sign Up process takes extremely long, responds after about 2 minutes (when all it has to do is run a couple of queries agains the db?)
- File uploads (on carrierwave) are so slow they are practically not working. (files are going to S3 via Fog on CarrierWave).

The code in the above instances is pretty straight forward and I don't see anything obviously wrong. In fact, most of the work gets performed by the gems (e.g. devise handles registrations and logins). any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What exactly is the question here?  What sort of answers are you expecting?

Comment: I am expecting if I missed something obvious, if some of the gems I have are the issue OR something wrong with EC2 instance size itself. got it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use a analytics tool, like [New Relic](https://newrelic.com/)

This will help you locate te slowest code and/or the slowest db query

<strike>**EDIT**</strike>

On the comments below you have mentioned that you are using devise `0.5.8`, this is very bad, considering that devise is, today, at version `2.1.2`

Please update your devise and keep me posted.

**NEW EDIT**

Since the devise version is not the problem you could look into the views.

In the views check for http requests that could be inserted on a single request or a async request.

For instance `Google Analytics`.

If the load of their javascript files are blocking your view to load maybe putting them on `head` or making them `async` could help

Comment: this tells me that RegistrationController#create is the slowest (23secs average response time), this is devise code. So I think I'll need to upgrade my instance size to Large? I doubt devise guys wrote slow code.

Comment: that depends, are you using any database index? this could improve the queries that devise uses. But i really never user devise in production, so i cant say why.

Comment: can you post here your `RegistrationController#create` ?

Comment: NewRelic says DB is hardly using 1% of the time, it's all taken by ruby. RegistrationController#create is form devise gem, I don't have the source code, I can copy it from their site though?

Comment: what is the exact version of the devise gem? you can see in the `Gemfile.lock`

Comment: 0.5.8 :) sorry should have mentioned it earlier

Comment: sorry you are right, I am using 2.1.2, I foolishly copied CarrierWave version earlier. So, I am using the latest version. yes, I'll accept this if this solves my issue, thank you.

Comment: Nicos, I have found cause of the slowness, sometimes the views take extremely long to render (20 seconds on the average), I am looking into it. Please edit your answer to include this information (and remove the bit about wrong devise version since I am using latest, i had mistakenly given you the version of CarrierWave earlier)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to compile a Ruby 1.9.3-p194 with falcon patch, it increases ruby and rails speed dramatically.
[falcon patch in rvm](https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/blob/master/patches/ruby/1.9.3/p194/falcon.diff)

You download ruby src and apply this patch if you do not want to use RVM.

It might also be a DNS issue if some parameter for reverse DNS lookup enabled in Apache configuration.

Answer (score -1):

Just put gem [rails tweak](https://github.com/wavii/rails-dev-tweaks) in your gem file and after that run

```
bundle install
```

I think it will solve your problem.

Thanks

Comment: right now github is down, am waiting for it to come back, will keep you posted. thanks again.

Comment: installed, the upload is still very slow, I'm using S3 for file storage (CarrierWave gem), I'll try storing files to my own server's disk and see.

Comment: development? sorry I think we are not on the same page, I am facing this slowness in production environment (on EC2), or did I miss something?

Comment: ok, let me check if anything can be done, will let you know. I think there is some problem with device, really it works slow.

Comment: This gem, from what i see, will only work in development, to improve performance on the development server only, nothing that could help the current slow down problem